# Как запустить sudo для одной команды, а для следующих заново вводить пароль?

Tags: bash

Допустим, мы хотим создать папку в директории. Но в правах мы ограничены.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/TestDir
[Enter password]
```

Папка создалась, но последующие sudo будут запускаться без ввода пароля.

```
sudo -i mkdir /mnt/TestDir
[Enter password]
```

И тут тоже самое.

Answer (score 1):

Система какое-то время помнит введённый пароль (сохраняет открытой sudo-сессию). Поэтому при последующих выполнениях sudo ввод пароля может не потребоваться. Для гарантированного прекращения сессии sudo наберите в терминале

```
sudo

  -K, --remove-timestamp        полностью удалить файл
                                    timestamp
  -k, --reset-timestamp         объявить
                                    недействительным файл
                                    timestamp
```

Узнавайте большее из документации ([ссылка](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B2_ubuntu)).

Answer (score 1):

добавьте в `/etc/sudoers` (открыв его в любимом редакторе с помощью команды `$ sudo visudo`) такую, например, строку:

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=0
```

тем самым установив время жизни меток времени (для повторного ввода пароля) в ноль минут.

теперь пароль будет запрашиваться каждый раз при выполнении программы *sudo* (ну, кроме как с некоторыми спецопциями типа `-k`, `-l` и т.п.).

---

доп. чтение:

```
$ man 5 sudoers
$ man sudo
```